# JS split method, include separator in array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, split

I would like to split a set of div elements, for further text-processing in an array. A simple mockup:

```
var divElements = prompt('Input');
array = divElements.split('</div>')
console.log(array);
```

Input:

```
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
<div id="3"></div>
<div id="4"></div>
```

Output for now:

```
array
["<div id="1">", "
<div id="2">", "
<div id="3">", "
<div id="4">", ""]
```

but I would like to include the separator (div closing tag) inside the array to keep the html syntax intact. As a result the array should have these four items:

```
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
<div id="3"></div>
<div id="4"></div>
```

Comment: You should parse it as HTML instead of trying to split.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

split() method also takes regex to split strings. In your case use the regex \s(?=\<).

```
    var divElements = prompt('Input');
    array = divElements.split(/\s(?=\<)/);
    console.log(array);
```

regex explantion

- \s - any space character
- (?=\<) - followed by < character (positive look ahead)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a regular expression, to look ahead for the next `div`.

```js
var str = '<div id="1"></div><div id="2"></div><div id="3"></div><div id="4"></div>';

var arr = str.split(/(?=<div)/);

console.log(arr);
```

If you want to separate but keep the delimiter, you can use [capturing parenthesis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split#Capturing_parentheses).

```js
var str = '<div id="1"></div><div id="2"></div><div id="3"></div><div id="4"></div>';

var arr = str.split(/(<\/div>)/);

console.log(arr);
```

That said, you *really* should **not** do string operations, or [regular expression parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2505965), on data that you know is HTML. Attributes might contain HTML-like patterns, and then you're out of luck.

Plunk it into a container element, and work on it that way, or use a proper parser.

```js
var data = '<div id="1"></div><div id="2"></div><div id="3"></div><div id="4"></div>';

var ele = document.createElement('div');

ele.innerHTML = data;

console.log(ele.childNodes)
```